# Storing Malformed Unicode Strings in Postgres

Tags: java, postgresql, google-maps-api-3, unicode

I want to store a string like following in one of my database tables:

```
ygei@kqmfNk@?w@Ac@l@}CbEoD|EM`@MLK@KCKS[e@W[[o@yAuCSUi@[G@KAII?MFk@?cAKWIQ?YFIDEd@cBzA}KvBuPX}B`BwLt@iFFEzE}AlDaA|JqC@y
```

This is in fact a portion of a google maps encoded route. When I try to store this string in a text field I get the error:

```
  invalid Unicode escape
  Hint: Unicode escapes must be \uXXXX or \UXXXXXXXX.
  Position: 123
```

How could I fix this?

**Edit:**

> Postgres Version: 9.0, Both Server and Client runs on Windows 7 x86,
>   Server encoding: UTF8, Client encoding: Unicode

I issued the command from a java application to store the value in a text field in the table

Comment: Is that the real string? Looks like simple ASCII to me.

Comment: Start by providing your Postgres version, the (relevant part of) the command you issued, the client and OS you used, the OS of your DB server and the settings for client- and server-encoding: `SHOW server_encoding;` `SHOW client_encoding;`

Comment: @muistooshort, how could I mitigate the error? I am not sure whether converting the database encoding to ASCII would help.

Comment: That string looks like ASCII, I see nothing in there that isn't a plain old 7bit ASCII character so there's no way to know what the problem is. Are you sure that the error is coming from PostgreSQL rather than Java?

Comment: @muistooshort you were correct. When I manually entered the string to the table it worked. I have wrongly identified the error being thrown from Postgres. Actually error is thrown by org.postgresql.util.PSQLException. Do you know of anyway that I could fix this at the java end?

Comment: I don't see enough information to know what the problem is and I'm more of a PostgreSQL guy than a Java guy.

Comment: @muistooshort thanks very much for your insight. I now can explore the options efficiently.

Comment: That's not the string causing the error. It doesn't have 123 characters in it. Find the string causing the error and see what it has either side of character 123. It may be that one of the Java libs sees a literal "\u" and then tries to turn it into a unicode escape.

Comment: @Richard It is rather at position 123 than character 123 as I can see.

Answer (score 0):

First, SQL-ASCII allows you to store this sort of thing as it doesn't do any encoding checking.  However, in general this is to be discouraged.  If you aren't doing enforcement of encoding, then you probably want to be aware of that at first.

Is there any reason you can't store the field as bytea and just treat the data as arbitrary binary data?